# How can i fixed safari sub-pixel bug on elements with overflow: hidden?

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to create a box with label on left top angle. This label must slide on mouse over.

When I hover on this box In Safari Browser (Mac OS El Capitan) I watch the following bug: http://newsletters.loginov.biz/1.png

When the transition is complete yellow label becomes ok (clipping is well).

NB! I discovered that this happens when the viewport width is odd. (You can resize browser step by step to see this problem).

Any ideas?

```css
.box { 
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden; 
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #212121;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 250ms;
transition: box-shadow 250ms;
}

.box:after { 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
top: 0; 
right: 0; 
border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
border-top: 120px solid #ffcc32; 
content: ''; 
-webkit-transform: translate(30px, -60px);
transform: translate(30px, -60px);
-webkit-transition: transform 250ms;
transition: transform 250ms;
}

.box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 45px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
.box:hover:after { 
-webkit-transform: none;
transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img src="http://s.appleinsider.ru/2016/06/macOS-Sierra-Wallpaper-iPhone-Plus-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="test img" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is not an elegant solution, but helped me with exactly the same problem.
In my case there were multiple elements in row and issue was reproduced when wrapper element was centered. So when wrapper has odd width while viewport has odd width too it can't be perfectly centrified in Safari (the same for even width). So your wrapper had to have an opposite fold.
JQuery in my solution is for fast add/remove class - you can use your own methods.

```
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper'), fixSafariSubpixelDelay;
function fixSafariSubpixel() {
  clearTimeout(fixSafariSubpixelDelay);
  fixSafariSubpixelDelay = setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth % 2 == 0)
      $wrapper.removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
    else
      $wrapper.removeClass('odd').addClass('even');
  }, 100);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', fixSafariSubpixelDelay);
```